# SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Using `spark-streaming` to consume data from `Kafka` and then write it to `HDFS` in `orc` format.

The data stored in `Kafka` is like:

```
hadoop
hive
impala
hive
```

My codes:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder.master("local[4]")
      .appName("SpeedTester")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "3g")
      .getOrCreate()

    val ds = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.95.20:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "trial")
      .option("startingOffsets" , "earliest")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value as string)")
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("orc")
      .option("path", "hdfs://192.168.95.19:8022/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/demo")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
```

The codes can successfully write data in `text` format to `HDFS`. However, when I change it into `orc` format, it returns:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://192.168.95.19:8022/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/demo/part-00000-cfd9991f-e503-4140-811b-a00f7da7191e-c000.snappy.orc
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1262)
```

What is the reason to this question and how to address it? 
Any help is appreciated.

---

By the way, the `Hive` table create sentence:

```
create table test.demo (demo string)
stored as orc;
```

Comment: have to tried to look in HDFS to find out that the folders are not empty and that the user that is running the Spark process has permissions to read from the folder?

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez Thanks for your reply. All related folders have been removed and I submit the spark job using `sudo -u hdfs` so it should have the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new hive session and then use that to store data in ORC format. The code would look like (Untested as I do not have access to any spark cluster) :

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder.master("local[4]")
  .appName("SpeedTester")
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "3g")
  .getOrCreate()

// create a new hive context from the spark context
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(spark)


// create the data frame and write it to orc
// output will be a directory of orc files
val ds = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.95.20:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "trial")
  .option("startingOffsets" , "earliest")
  .load()

ds.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .format("orc")
  .save("hdfs://192.168.95.19:8022/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/demo/")
}
```

Try this out and let me know weather it works or not !!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply~. I am dealing with an error when generating the `hive_context`. But it seems that the `hiveContext` is not used.

Comment: Did this solution worked ? If yes upvote the answer !! ;-)